# cf9 cffileupload - uploads file but progress par shows error

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion-9

I am having issues with the cffileupload function in ColdFusion9. I when I select upload, it uploads the first files to the correct location, but the progress bar shows in red and says error. If I hit upload again, it does the exact same thing with the next file.  In the browse console it shows Status: 500. I have googled this issue and have not found a answer. Has anyone been able to get this to work correctly?

submission.cfm:

```
<cfset session.myuploadroot = "\\coldfusion\devl\uploads\cfeis_redbook\">

 <form action="submission.cfm" method="post">
 <cffileupload extensionfilter="xls,xlsx,doc,docx,pdf" name="bfiles" maxfileselect="3" title="Portfolio Images" url="fileupload.cfm?#urlEncodedFormat(session.urltoken)#" oncomplete="handleComplete">
</form>
```

fileupload.cfm

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "filedata")>
<cffile action="upload" filefield="filedata" destination="#session.myuploadroot#" nameconflict="overwrite" result="result">
</cfif>

<cfset str.STATUS = 200>
<cfset str.MESSAGE = "passed">
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(str)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: did you try with action="uploadall" instead of "upload". <cffile action="uploadall" filefield="filedata" destination="#session.myuploadroot#" >